# Cutting multiple polygons by line using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have more than 45,000 polygons, and I want to cut these polygons by lines that contain 267 lines. If I cut these polygons one by one using the "Cut Polygon" tools, it takes a long time.

How can I cut these polygons by lines at once?

This is the polygons layer.

[image]

And this is the lines layer.

[image]

Comment: Read this [help page](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/splitting-a-polygon-by-an-overlapping-line-feature.htm).

Comment: You could also use the geoprocessing tool [Feature to Polygon](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/feature-to-polygon.htm#S_GUID-7405FC72-FF8F-4B08-858F-F0F5E613DFA0).

Comment: You had a tag for ArcPy but have not included a code attempt so I removed it.